# How to run a for loop for multiple textboxes

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have multiple text boxes, it is tedious to write code for all text boxes so I would like to run a loop for text boxes.
But I don't know how to do it and I want to do if any changes occur in any text box the corresponding other text box value should also change.
I am programming this in a Windows Forms application using Visual Studio 2015.
I have tried below code but it didn't work.

```
 Private Sub q1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles q1.TextChanged
        v1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(q1.Text * i1_1.Text)
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are ways to do this but you would have to specify the relationship among `v1`, `q1` and `i1_1` somewhere.  For instance, you might have a `Dictionary` where `q1` was a key and `v1` and/or `i1_1` were values.  You could then have one event handler for `q1`, `q2`, etc, and you could access which one raised the event from the `sender` parameter and then use that to get the other(s) from the `Dictionary`.  If you want more information then I suggest that you provide more information about the relationships among the controls.

Comment: for now just tell me how can i run loop for multiple text box

Comment: You may not even need a loop so I'm not going to waste my time and yours explaining something that will require me to make a number of assumptions and that you may not even need.  Maybe provide the information I asked for and then I can address your actual problem rather than the one you think you have.

Comment: `For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count Me.Controls("v" & i).Text = <YourText> End For`. This will loop over all controls on your forms. If you just want your text boxes you have to filter it , e.g. via linq.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adapt this code to your need

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(Textbox)) Then
           ....
        End If
    Next
```